# Is there any JAR libraries that allow to create global Windows hotkeys?

Tags: java, hotkeys

I want to create such application where it performs some action on clicking hotkey, BUT these hotkeys should be able to be pressed without being focused on my application. I mean, you could run some game(for example) and these global hotkeys stll work.

SO...is there any JAR libraries that allow to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at JNativeHook: https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/